# Sequential playback of audio files overlap using .addEventListener ended

Tags: javascript, audio, addeventlistener

The following code is intended to play a series of short audio files in a sequence, as held in a javascript array named `audio_sequence`.

an `.addEventListener('ended',function())` is used to trigger playback of each audio clip in the sequence.

This works as expected for the first 5 items in the array, playing each in turn, but then the audio elements start to play simultaneously and the sequence becomes jumbled.

I have tried several different approaches all yielding similar results. 
Would very much appreciate any insights.

And example of the code running can be found here:
[Play Sequence](http://thegeorge.imageweavers.co.uk/sequence.html)

Here's the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var game_sounds = ["rooms", "bars", "food", "inveraray", "arse"];
var game_sequence = [0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4];    
var sequence_position = 0;

function play_next(){
    if (sequence_position < game_sequence.length){
        var audioElement = document.getElementById(game_sounds[game_sequence[sequence_position]]);                                                      
        audioElement.addEventListener('ended', function(){
            sequence_position++;
            play_next();
        }, true);
        audioElement.play();
    }
}

function playSequence(){
    sequence_position = 0;
    var audioElement = document.getElementById(game_sounds[game_sequence[sequence_position]]);
//  alert(game_sounds[game_sequence[sequence_position]]);
    audioElement.addEventListener('ended', function(){
        sequence_position++;
        play_next();
    },true);
    audioElement.play();
}

</script>
```

& the html is as follows:

```
<a onClick="javascript:playSequence();" href="#"><h2>Play Sequence</h2></a>

<audio hidden id="rooms" preload="auto">
    <source src="/audio/rooms.mp3">
</audio>
<audio hidden id="food" preload="auto">
    <source src="/audio/food.mp3" >
</audio>
<audio hidden id="bars" preload="auto">
    <source src="/audio/bars.mp3">
</audio>
<audio hidden id="inveraray" preload="auto">
    <source src="/audio/inveraray.mp3">
</audio>
<audio hidden id="arse" preload="auto">
    <source src="/audio/arse.mp3">
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is causing the problem is that you are attaching the same event listener several times to each element, as they are in a loop. In a non particularly elegant but effective workaround, you could remove the listener before attaching it again:

```
var game_sounds = ["rooms", "bars", "food", "inveraray", "arse"];
var game_sequence = [0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4];    
var sequence_position = 0;

function play_next(){
    if (sequence_position < game_sequence.length){
        playSequence();
    }
}

function playSequence(){
    var audioElement = document.getElementById(game_sounds[game_sequence[sequence_position]]);
//  alert(game_sounds[game_sequence[sequence_position]]);
    audioElement.removeEventListener('ended', prepareNextAudio);
    audioElement.addEventListener('ended', prepareNextAudio, true);
    audioElement.play();
}

function prepareNextAudio() {
    sequence_position++;
    play_next();
}
```

This code works and stops the playlist when each audio has been played for three times, which I guess is what you needed.

Comment: Yes. That resolves the issue. Many thanks. Much appreciated.